# how to compress image in a flutter web program

Tags: image, flutter, web, compression

I try to upload the image in a flutter web program but the size of it is too large. After cropping it, the problem cannot be solved. The data format of the image is Uint8List.

Comment: did you anything work?

Answer (score 0):

Just using new Plugin name : File_support
url : https://pub.dev/packages/file_support

This file support plugin is good when I used first time.It drastically reduce file size 2 mb to 70 kb.

```html
 File compressimage = await FileSupport().compressImage(<Your image file>);
```

After this code convert File object to Uint8 then upload file.